# Prism 6.2 Binding to Model not ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I am trying to use `Prism` in a C# to but I seem to have set it up so that it binds to items in my model and not my viewmodel.  It is a short program that is more of a learning tool that anything.  When I move the items to the Viewmodel the SetProperty's don't seem to notify the view of the change.

Any thoughts as to how I have this setup backwards?

Model:

```
namespace XMLValueModifier_Threaded_WPF.Models
{
    public class XMLReadFileModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _XMLMasterFile2 = "0";

        public string XMLGetFileName()
        {
            if (_XMLMasterFile2 != "1")
                {
                    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog _XMLMasterFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

                    _XMLMasterFileDialog.DefaultExt = "xml";
                    _XMLMasterFileDialog.Filter = "xml Files (*.xml; *.XML) | *.xml; *.XML";

                    Nullable<bool> result = _XMLMasterFileDialog.ShowDialog();

                    if (result == true)
                    {
                        return _XMLMasterFileDialog.FileName;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace XMLValueModifier_Threaded_WPF.ViewModels
{
    public class MainDialogueViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _XMLMasterFile;

        public ICommand MasterFileLocation
        {
            get;
            set; 
        }

        public ICommand XMLFileLocation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string XMLMasterFile
        {
            get
            {
                return _XMLMasterFile;
            }
            set
            {

                SetProperty(ref _XMLMasterFile, value);
            }
        }

        private XMLReadFileModel xmlReadFileModel = new XMLReadFileModel();
        public MainDialogueViewModel()
        {
            XMLReadFileModel xmlReadFileModel = new XMLReadFileModel();
            Message = "example message";
            XMLMasterFile = "example File";

            this.MasterFileLocation = new DelegateCommand(chooseFile, canChooseFile);
            this.XMLFileLocation = new DelegateCommand(chooseFile, canChooseFile);
        }

        public void masterfilelocation()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("i am here");
            return;
        }

        private void chooseFile()
        {
           XMLMasterFile = xmlReadFileModel.XMLGetFileName();
        }

        private bool canChooseFile()
        {
            if (XMLMasterFile != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="XMLValueModifier_Threaded_WPF.Views.MainDialogue"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XMLValueModifier_Threaded_WPF.ViewModels" Width="625" Height="452"
    >

<Grid Margin="0,-24,0,-3">
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="{Binding MainDialogueViewModel.XMLMasterFile,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="25,120,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox2" Text="{Binding MainDialogueViewModel.XMLFiles,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="25,188,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425" RenderTransformOrigin="0.506,1.565"/>
    <Label Content="Location of Master XML File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Location of XML File(s)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/></GRID>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your DataContext setup correctly to an instance of MainDialogueViewModel; you don't need to include MainDialogueViewModel in your binding.  Simply bind to the property name XMLMasterFile.  Also keep in mind that if the value isn't different, then nothing will be updated.

Comment: When I step through the debugger I can see the XMLMasterFile value change, but the view is not updated. Where would I see if the DataContext is setup correctly? I thought that the xmlns:local would point the binding to the correct place if no DataContext was used

Comment: No, the local namespace does nothing for DataContext. You must set the View's DataContext to an instance of your ViewModel before you can use any bindings.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I took out the MainDialogueViewModel and it is now working.